# how to remove route from $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to remove a route from $routeProvider ?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {$routeProvider
.when('/test', {
    templateUrl:'/index.html',
controller: 'mainCtrl'
})});
```

How to remove the '/test' route from provider as well as templatecache ?

Comment: It is very easy ! Just delete that part of the code :D

Comment: thx for suggestion :) Actually im populating the routes from db according to user roles & authorized companies.So User is able to change the company he is working on.routes are supposed to change accordingly.btw i moved routeProvider from config to run using extanding app.(as dan wahlin did)

Comment: Do you have a link to Dan's article or something describing how to do this ?

Comment: im trying to following snippet but no way.for (var mappedRoute in $route.routes) {

                    if (mappedRoute.indexOf('error404') == -1 &&
                        mappedRoute.indexOf('error500') == -1) {
                        delete $route.routes[mappedRoute];
                        $templateCache.remove(mappedRoute);
                    }
                } you can take a look at the CustomerManager sample by dan wahlin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in order to remove the route you need to:

1. have access to `$route.routes`.
2. know the path you want to remove.
3. have access to `$templateCache`.
4. find out the `templateUrl` associated with the path.

(Keep in mind that `$routeProvider` always registers two routes: one with a trailing `/` and one without - just to cover both cases.)

```
function headerCtrl($location, $route, $scope, $templateCache) {
    ...
    // For simplicity's sake we assume that:
    //  1. `path` has no trailing `/`
    //  2. the route associated with `path` has a `templateUrl`
    //  3. everything exists, so we don't check for empty values
    $scope.removeRoute = function (path) {
        var route1  = $route.routes[path];
        var route2  = $route.routes[path + '/'];
        var tmplUrl = $route.routes[path].templateUrl;

        $templateCache.remove(tmplUrl);
        delete(route1);
        delete(route2);

        // It might also be a good idea 
        // to move to another, default path
        $location.path('/');
    };
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/zdf56/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.did u try to access removed route after removing ?Angular is supposed to redirect to otherwiseTo route.However $routeChangeSuccess are fired with currentRoute undefined instead of redirecting otherwiseTo route.Am i missing smthing ?

Comment: I don't know what you tried. In my fiddle you can see that after removing the route and trying to access it you get redirected to the `otherwiseTo` route.